# Bengali Input method in lubuntu

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I've newly installed Lubuntu as I've found Ubuntu 14.4 very slow in my old computer, and only with 1 GB of Ram. I've installed Bengali and Assamese in Language Support. After that I cannot find the Bengali input method in the i-bus preference.

After googling a lot, I've found that `Avro` can be used for Bengali Typing. I've installed Avro. It has only one keyboard layout i.e. `Phonetic`. But I am accustomed to `inscript` layout only.

Is there any way, that I can install Uni Gitanjali as input methods? or can I configure my keys in Avro itself. In windows Avro key board can be configured by users. But I cannot find anything like that in Lubuntu.