# uni gitanjali in lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, input-method

In Ubuntu we have multiple choice to type in Bengali language. We change our keyboard to `Bornona`, `uni gitanjali`, or some other. But in Lubuntu it is a kind of pain. Is there any option so that I can type bengali in `uni gitanjali` which is an inscript keyboard.

Or is there any other option, so that I can have an `Inscript` input method?

Comment: Please do not [reask](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626159/bengali-input-method-in-lubuntu) questions only because noone answered: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3722/should-i-ask-the-same-question-again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look for keyboard layouts, have you tried to search for Bangla?

As regards IBus input methods, you may want to install the **ibus-m17n** package. That should make a few Bengali (not Bangla - yes, it's confusing) options available in IBus Preferences.

Comment: @PranjalCholadhara: Yeah, I know. Just wished that Bangla was used consistently all over the desktop. `ibus-m17n` is an exception in that respect.